# dateutil.parser - separate hours and minutes with dot

Tags: python, python-dateutil

I use the `dateutil.parser.parse` function to recognize a date entered by a user. Normally hours and minutes are separated by a double point but sometimes a user enters something like `6.30pm` which is parsed to 18:00. So the minutes are just dropped.

```
>>> dateutil.parser.parse ('6.30pm')
datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 14, 18, 0)
```

Is there a way to specify the dot as a legal separator or throw a `ValueError` if the user uses the wrong separator? I want to show at least an error message to the user and not just process the wrong recognized date.

Comment: I might be late, but I stumble upon this thread on my journey. I came to believe dateutil parser does not "want" to understand a dot as hour-minute separator because a dot is a decimal (second) separator, as used in e.g. `12:24:50.00.09`. That might explain why. The accepted answer also (in time of my writing) demonstrate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a little substitution previous the parsing operation, something like:

```
import dateutil.parser
import re

def parse(timestr):
    timestr = re.sub(r"(\d{1,2})\.(\d{2})(\D*)$", r"\1:\2\3", timestr)
    return dateutil.parser.parse(timestr)

print(parse('6.30pm')) # >> 2019-05-14 18:30:00
print(parse('12:06.30')) # >> 2019-05-14 12:06:30
print(parse('2018-01-01 12:06:05.123'))  # >> 2018-01-01 12:06:05.123000
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. The only case where its not working is when a user enters first the time and then the date like ```6.30pm 05/04/2019``` but I think that's super uncommon.

Comment: Indeed, but that could be avoided with a more complex regex and by adding a new capturing group. Here is a good website to learn and try your regex: https://regexr.com/